# Azure MSAL - Authentication cannot realize userinfo request

Tags: azure, authentication, active-directory, openid, azure-ad-msal

I've implemented msal library in my angular application using **Implicit Flow**. I can login using microsoft ad account and I have the token needed for authentication requests for api usage. 
When I decode token using https://jwt.ms/ I can see that aud key has value of my **client app id**, how should look like the url for userinfo? 
If I will use these endpoints which are described in docs I had error with invalid token:
https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo or
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "8177b64f-c899-48c3-aceb-xxxxxxxxx",
        "date": "2020-03-18T07:41:04"
    }
}
```

}

I've forgot to put my module config.

```
...
MsalModule.forRoot({
                    auth: {
                        clientId: environment.CLIENT_ID,
                        redirectUri: environment.REDIRECT_URI,
                        postLogoutRedirectUri: environment.POST_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URI,
                        authority: environment.AUTHORITY,
                    },
                    cache: {
                        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
                        storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
                    }
                },
                {
                    popUp: false,
                    consentScopes: [
                        'user.read',
                        'openid',
                        'profile',
                    ],
                    unprotectedResources: [],
                    protectedResourceMap: [
                        ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']]
                    ]
                })
...
```

where:
authority url: Authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxtenant_idxxxx'
client id: App registration client id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call Microsoft Graph API, you need get the access token with the correct(Microsoft graph api) audience.

When you acquire the access token, you should use `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read` or just `User.Read` as the scope. You can check the values in app.module.ts

Also, remember to add the `User.Read` permission for your application on Azure portal. App registrations->your application->API permissions->Add a permission->Choose Microsoft Graph API->Delegated permission->Check the permissions you need.

**Update:**

[image]

Reference:

[MSAL Angular to login, logout, protect a route, and acquire an access token for Microsoft Graph.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular)

Comment: Ok I have in all the same configuration for msal. But something I didn't do is this permissions in app registrations. I will check it

Comment: @TeK This error is due to the wrong audience. You can check the values in app.module.ts

Comment: Can You please verify my updated app.module? I still have problem, I dont change anything in app.module

Comment: @TeK Have you checked both Access tokens and ID tokens in your application?

Comment: @TeK How did you get the access token?

Comment: @TeK What is the value of aud in your token?

Comment: I've coppied Bearer token from my request to api. This bearer token is from msal interceptor i guess. Aud value is an client id app. The same value which is in environment.client_id

Comment: @TeK The token is not correct. I just tested the sample code and it worked fine.

Comment: @TeK Can you have a try with the sample?

Comment: But i don't have direct access to azure portal apps (corporate). Only read-only for app registration. 
https://pasteboard.co/IZE1GlC.png
https://pasteboard.co/IZE29f5.png

Comment: @TeK This error doesn't related to azure portal app.

Comment: You're trying to authenticate via common method or tenant id? (authority URL)

Comment: @TeK I used the tenant id

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem is in specified endpoint. When I make request for graph from angular the app interceptor handle this endpoint and use scope (user.read) for graph, and then the correct token will be assigned. 
Before I was trying to copy token after authorization and pasting it into postman. So yep, the token was not valid in all.. Thank's for your help.